# Joomla Image path on article pages

Tags: php, .htaccess, joomla

This is driving me insane!

1. My joomla image folder is "images"
2. Images appear fine on my home page
3. when I create an article the image path turns into article_name/images but the correct path is /images and in global + media settings it shows images
4. I disabled SEF, cleared cache F -**no difference**
5. I tried to disable URL rewriting - **no difference**
6. Even the site logo path changes on a article page to article_name/images/imagename.jpg when it should be images/imagename.jpg
7. The joomla site is installed in the public_html folder

Is there a rewrite condition I can use in htaccess file to make sure images always load from the images folder and do not have the article name added?

Comment: Sorry it is not using the article page its using the category in the image url path. EG http://categoryname/images/imagename.jpg

should be http://images/imagename.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I found a link which might solve the problem. Here's the link: https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=298582

> Modify inlcudes/application.php at row 108, from this:
>
> Code: Select all
>
> $document->setBase(JURI::current());
>
> to this:
>
> Code: Select all
>
> $document->setBase(JURI::base())
>    ;

Comment: there is no application.php file in /includes just defines, framework and index

Comment: Also the link relates to sh404sef which is a plugin i'm not using